# Execute query for copy data from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing an android application. The Login and Registration page of this application is connected with a php page and data is storing into mySql database through php page. Now, when the user clicks on Registration button, the data should be save in database through php. This is working fine. When the user clicks on Login then Username and password should be verify. This one too working fine. But When user clicks on Login, I want to copy data from one table to another table right after Username and Password verification. A flag should be set to '1' and sent to android. But If I add query for copy data in php code, then none of the query is executing and Flag is not sending to android application. If I comment **$select3 Query**,its working fine.Please give me solution. I am completely new in php and mysql. Look at the below code :

```
    <?php
    // Connection...

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Uname']); 
    $password =mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Password']);

    $flag['code']=0;

    $select2="update Table1 SET TimeIN=NOW() where BINARY Uname=BINARY'$name' AND BINARY Password = BINARY'$password'";

    $select3 = "insert into Table2 (Uname,Password,Email,Mobile,IP_Address,TimeIN,TimeOUT)select   Uname,Password,Email,Mobile,IP_Address,Time,Timeout from Insert1 where BINARY Uname = BINARY '$name' AND BINARY Password = BINARY'$password';"

    $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from Table1 where BINARY Uname = BINARY'$name' AND BINARY Password = BINARY'$password'"); 

    $s=mysqli_query($con,$select2);
    $t=mysqli_query($con,$select3);
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($num_rows > 0) 
    { 
       $flag['code']=1;
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: have you tried to print $select3 query and execute in directly in mysql?

Comment: yess...its working fine in mysql..but not using php...The `$flag['code']` should be set to 0 or 1..but nothing is happening...

Comment: use try catch to see if php throw some error. but it looks strange that $select3 query mess up with setting flag,as that part of the code is eqecuted if query below that one return more then 0 rows.

Comment: okk...lemme use try and catch thenn...

Comment: You insert into `Table2` from `Insert1`- how can you be sure that the user exists in `Table1`?

Comment: plus in general use mysqli_error for all queries,it can become handy in some situation

Comment: @serakfalcon first user will enter his username and password. according to that username and password it will verify first which is in `$result` query...now in $select3, that username and password will be apply to search the corrosponding data to copy in another table...

Comment: Ok I'll be clear. At no point in the given code do you insert into `Table1`. If the information already exists there, great, if not, then, even if the rest of your code works, `$flag['code']` will still be 0.

Comment: @serakfalcon YESSS...The information is already exists that's why the username and password is verified from database. but the flag should be set to 0 first...why its not happning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can better use a Mysqli-object. for example:

```
$database = new mysqli(url, username, password, database);
$query = $database->stmt_init($select);
$query->execute();
```

But it is safer to use prepared statements:

```
$query = $database->stmt_init();
$query->prepare("update Table1 SET TimeIN=NOW() where Uname=? AND BINARY Password = ?");
$query->bind_param("ss", $uname, $password); //with ss you say you will bind two strings to the question marks.
$query->execute();
```

to read the data:

```
$query = $database->stmt_init();
$query->prepare("select * from Table1 where Uname =? AND Password =?;");
$query->bind_param("ss", $uname, $password); 
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->num_rows;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you and sorry..!! I can't change my complete code RIGHT NOW...I'll remind it for another database...But whts the problem here in $select3 query..??? why it is blocking all other queries..??

Comment: I guess you should first execute $select2 and $select3 before you get the result.
    $s=mysqli_query($con,$select2);
    $t=mysqli_query($con,$select3);
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from Table1 where BINARY Uname = BINARY'$name' AND BINARY Password = BINARY'$password'");

Comment: Have you already tried to execute the query in phpmyadmin or another database tool?

Comment: I am using UBUNTU...i tried this query in mysql terminal..its working fine there..but using php code..its not working...the main point is why $select3 blocking all other queries...!!! If I comment this query, all will work properly...!!!

Comment: Is it true there's no ";" after $select3 = ...?

Comment: thank you for your last comment...!!! no one did notice this thing except you...that was a miner mistake and made me in trouble....thank you so much....:D :D